# How are expressions evaluated?

Tags: javascript

The following code prints `6`. This means that the variable `x` appears to have the value of *both* `3` (for the left `x` in the expression) and `2` (the result of the decrement).

```js
let x = 3
console.log(x * --x) // 6 (NOT 4)
```

Does this work because before it is logically executed, the expression values are copied into a buffer as the expression is parsed according to associativity (here left-to-right)?

Likewise in this recursive factorial solution, the initial value of `x` is retained (for each time through `factorial`) *after* the recursive function call has returned, despite the decrement having occurred by that time.

```js
function factorial(x) {
  if(!x) return 1
  return x * factorial(--x)
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `*` operator works like this:

1. Evaluate the left-hand operand; in this case, `x` yields `3`.
2. Evaluate the right-hand operand. Since `--x` means "decrement `x` in place and give me the decremented value" that yields `2`.
3. Multiply the result of Step 1 with the result of Step 2 and take that as the operation result.

It's covered in the spec [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-evaluatestringornumericbinaryexpression), in a section used for lots of the binary operators that can be applied to numbers or strings.

So yes, in a sense you could say that the values are stored in a buffer prior to being multiplied. That buffer is likely to be a CPU register or stack location. In the case of the `factorial` example you gave, it'll be a stack location (though that's an implementation detail; the JavaScript engine can be implemented in any way provided it produces the specified results).